# How do I make . execute the last shell command in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, history, alias, command-history

In bash, `alias .= "fc -s"` works for this purpose, it does exactly what I want. But in zsh, using `fc -s` just outputs `fc: bad option: -s`.

How do I make . execute the last shell command in zsh?

Answer (score 2):

```
alias .='fc -e -'
```

Instead of creating a separate alias, you could use the `r` builtin, which is equivalent to the above.

You could also use [History Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion): `!!`.